# How to pass individual elements in an array in JQ to xargs

Tags: jq

I have an array like such:

```json
[
  {
    "customer": {
      "id": "61ae22891dbcb5200f4af298",
      "customerId": "C0001346",
      "companyName": "Real Constructions",
      "displayName": "Real Constructions",
      "fullName": "NiyatiU",
      "email": "niyati@curbwaste.com",
      "phone": "(987) 654-3209"
    },
    "address": {
      "streetName": "NY",
      "state": "NY",
      "city": "NY",
      "zipcode": "39092"
    }
  },
  {
    "customer": {
      "id": "61ae29f31dbcb5200f4af2b2",
      "customerId": "C0001347",
      "companyName": "UK Reality",
      "displayName": "UK Reality",
      "fullName": "VatsalShah",
      "email": "vatsal@curbwaste.com",
      "phone": "(766) 688-1348"
    },
    "address": {
      "streetName": "Queens",
      "state": "NY",
      "city": "Queens",
      "zipcode": "11354"
    }
  }
]
```

and I would like to pass each object as a seperate param to xargs and curl. Psuedo code like

```sh
jq '. | map(@json) | join("\\0")' http/customer/us/customers.json \
  | xargs -0 -n 1 -I % curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/customers -d '%'
```

But then I get:

```
xargs: insufficient space for argument
```

because the json element is too big, I'd assume. I'd prefer not write a bunch of files.

Comment: More specifically? xargs is going to treat the first space or newline as a delimiter - and there will definitely be spaces in the json - so it has to be nul delimited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
jq -j 'map(@json) | join("\u0000")' http/customer/us/customers.json |
   xargs -0 -I % curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/customers -d %
```

Since `@json` never produces any line feeds, the following would also work:

```sh
jq -r '.[] | @json' http/customer/us/customers.json |
   xargs -I % curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/customers -d %
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0z--Al_UbY) on jq play

- `--join-output`/`-j` prints the string as-is rather that rather than printing a JSON string literal that produces the string. Doesn't add any line feeds, not even a trailing one.
- `--raw-output`/`-r` prints the string as-is rather that rather than printing a JSON string literal that produces the string. Adds a line feed after each string.
- `"\\0"` doesn't produce a NUL. You want `"\u0000"` for that.
- `. |` is useless.
- There's no difference between `'%'` and `%`. They both pass `%` to `xargs`.
- `-n 1` is useless. `-I` implies `-L 1`, which renders `-n 1` redundant.
- `{}` is more commonly used as the replacement expression than `%`. But `%` is also fine, so I didn't change this.

Comment: I am going to give you the answer even though you and @pmf basically answered at the same time because yours is more thorough

Comment: I need to quote the json when sending it to curl - hence the `''`

Comment: @Christian Bongiorno, Re "*hence the `''`*", The quotes do no such thing. Like I said, `'%'` and `%` produces *exactly* the same argument. /// Re "*I need to quote the json when sending it to curl*" No. That would be bad. You aren't currently adding any form of quoting, and you should continue not adding any.

Comment: Ok, I am about to put that to the test - I am just using it like I would if I wasn't being fancy: `curl -X POST http://example.com -d '{"hello":"world"}'`

Comment: That passes `curl`, `-X`, `POST`, `http://example.com`, `-d`, `{"hello":"world"}` to `curl`. Notice the lack of quotes? No quoting should be added to the value passed to `curl`. And you're aren't. So all's good.

Comment: Using `xargs -0 -I % curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/customers -d %` passes `xargs`, `-0`, `-I`, `%`, `curl`, `-X`, `POST`, `http://localhost:3000/customers`, `-d` and `%` to `xargs`. Same goes if either/both `%` are in quotes. They are completely useless since `%` is not a special shell character.

Comment: Can I get an upvote for the question?

Comment: Ok, I tried what you gave, and what's being received by my server is:
`{
    "%": ""
}`. My exact cli : `jq 'map(@json) | join("\u0000")' http/invoice/us/invoices.json |
  xargs -0 -I % curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/companies/4620816365214377730/invoices -d %` - I even tried my `''` that shouldn't be necessary - same results. I tried it with `jq -r` and got rid of the `-0` in xargs. Same deal. Hmmm

Comment: WILD! If I remove the `-I %` and the `%` it starts treating a portion of the payload a key in a JSON object...

Comment: This substitution for `%` is definitely not working:
`jq '.[] | @json'  http/invoice/us/invoices.json |
  xargs  -I % -p curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3000/companies/4620816365214377730/invoices -d %
curl -H Content-Type: application/json -X POST http://localhost:3000/companies/4620816365214377730/invoices -d %?...

Comment: When I can pass it for xargs, For reasons I don't get, the entire json body is being stripped of quotes; hence why my parser treats it as a key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242601/discussion-between-christian-bongiorno-and-ikegami).

Comment: @Christian Bongiorno, If you have a new question, post a new Question. This is all unreadable and unclear.

Comment: Sorry - I solved that issue and started rambling. New question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71356034/select-random-id-from-list-in-jq-and-update-value

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--join-output` (or `-j`) option to output raw text with no newlines, and use `\u0000` to create the `NUL` character:

```sh
jq -j 'map(@json) | join("\u0000")' http/customer/us/customers.json \
  | xargs -0 -n 1 -I % curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/customers -d '%'
```