# Select random id from list in jq and update value

Tags: arrays, json, random, jq

I have some sample payload that I am going to be receiving, it looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "9",
    "Line": [
      {
        "Amount": 100,
        "Description": "Weekly Gardening Service",
        "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
        "Id": "1",
        "LineNum": 1,
        "SalesItemLineDetail": {
          "ItemAccountRef": {
            "name": "Landscaping Services",
            "value": "45"
          },
          "ItemRef": {
            "name": "Gardening",
            "value": "6"
          },
          "Qty": 4,
          "TaxCodeRef": {
            "value": "TAX"
          },
          "UnitPrice": 25
        }
      },
      {
        "Amount": 100,
        "DetailType": "SubTotalLineDetail",
        "SubTotalLineDetail": {}
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "10",
    "Line": [
      {
        "Amount": 140,
        "Description": "Weekly Gardening Service",
        "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
        "Id": "1",
        "LineNum": 1,
        "SalesItemLineDetail": {
          "ItemAccountRef": {
            "name": "Landscaping Services",
            "value": "45"
          },
          "ItemRef": {
            "name": "Gardening",
            "value": "6"
          },
          "Qty": 4,
          "TaxCodeRef": {
            "value": "NON"
          },
          "UnitPrice": 35
        }
      },
      {
        "Amount": 35,
        "Description": "Pest Control Services",
        "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
        "Id": "2",
        "LineNum": 2,
        "SalesItemLineDetail": {
          "ItemAccountRef": {
            "name": "Pest Control Services",
            "value": "54"
          },
          "ItemRef": {
            "name": "Pest Control",
            "value": "10"
          },
          "Qty": 1,
          "TaxCodeRef": {
            "value": "NON"
          },
          "UnitPrice": 35
        }
      },
      {
        "Amount": 175,
        "DetailType": "SubTotalLineDetail",
        "SubTotalLineDetail": {}
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

These I know are valid and I need to cross reference them, by id, in another payload I am receiving. But, the data I am receiving I can't assume to have valid ID's.

So, I want to take all the valid `Id`s from above, and shove them, randomly, into the sample data I have, that looks like this `($.invoices[].qbId)`:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "fb2430c5-5970-46b0-9947-aaa0b9f177bb",
    "invoices": [
      {
        "description": "2022-02-03 - 179",
        "dueDate": "2022-02-03T22:51:10.206Z",
        "id": "6f904b18-71c6-4fec-a016-7452f6a6b1dc",
        "invoiceDate": "2022-02-03T22:51:10.347Z",
        "openBalance": 200,
        "paidAmount": 200,
        "qbId": "1",
        "totalAmount": 212
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "fa5b77b5-bfd4-4178-ac31-386ec83f530c",
    "invoices": [
      {
        "description": "2022-01-12 - 95",
        "dueDate": "2022-01-12T14:08:26.219Z",
        "id": "05a58be3-4396-4c15-b9c2-ece68cb2b3fb",
        "invoiceDate": "2022-01-12T14:08:26.399Z",
        "openBalance": 7.33,
        "paidAmount": 7.33,
        "qbId": "",
        "totalAmount": 7.33
      },
      {
        "description": "2022-01-12 - 95",
        "dueDate": "2022-01-12T14:08:26.219Z",
        "id": "91f5ecd0-e18d-4029-8745-143323e02007",
        "invoiceDate": "2022-01-12T14:08:26.580Z",
        "openBalance": 53.13,
        "paidAmount": 53.13,
        "qbId": "",
        "totalAmount": 53.13
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

this jq will get me my ids `jq '.QueryResponse.Invoice | map(.Id)'` which can be readily consumed by jq. The question now is (and this is what I don't know) how to randomly choose from this array and update the sample payload:

```
jq 'map(. + {
   invoices : .invoices | map(. + {qbId: ??random here })
   })
'
```

Comment: Can you please shorten the JSON. These are much much larger than necessary to demonstration the problem

Comment: There are multiple `Id` fields in the first JSON, which is the one you are looking for?

Comment: I will shorten the JSON. @Inian see above: `.QueryResponse.Invoice | map(.Id)`

Comment: I shortened the json

Comment: `jq` does not implement a random number generator. The best thing you can do is to build upon `now` which also provides fractions. But if you want to reliably randomize something, you will have to externally generate the randomness and import it.

Comment: I've seen this: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1038#issuecomment-1030878399
But that only generates 1 id per invocation,. It doesn't need to be pure jq

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno `jq --arg varname …$RANDOM… ` is a kind of import I was talking about. `jq --arg varname …$(uuidgen)… ` would be another one.

Comment: But that gets me 1 selection per jq invocation - jq will be operating on an array

Comment: here's an idea: what if I carry the id list forward using `jq -s` like:
`jq -s '.' ids.json realinput.json` then `.[0]` are my ids I can randomize using `now % (.[0] | length)` it's not truly random but better than nothing

Comment: Something like this:
`
jq -s 'map(
.[1] + {
  invoices : .invoices | map (. 
    {
      qbId : ([0][(now % (.[0] | length))])
    })
}
'
` ids.json input.json

Comment: Why random? Why not assign the ids sequentially? Or generate fake ids with an incrementing counter (jq's `range(n)`)?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a snippet I use for creating random date strings using 'now' as a source for random. It should be simple to adapt it to generate indices in the array (map) of ids using the array length as an upper limit:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "{}" | jq '
    (now * 1000000) as $random |
    (($random * 3) % 10 + 2015 | tostring) as $year |
    (($random * 5) % 12 + 1 | tostring | ("0" + .) | .[0:2]) as $month |
    (($random * 7) % 28 + 1 | tostring | ("0" + .) | .[0:2]) as $day |
    ($year + "-" + $month + "-" + $day) as $randomDate |
    {randomDate: $randomDate}
'
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to replace each `id` field (spelling may differ, sometimes it's `Id`) with a randomly generated id string.

This solution first extracts the paths of all such id fields (in various spellings) using `jq`, then iterates over the result in the shell, using `uuidgen` to generate an id for each, which is fed into another `jq` call which uses `setpath` to change the value at the paths saved to the ids generated:

```sh
file="input.json"

jq -c '
  paths(.. | scalars) | select(.[-1] == ("id", "Id", "ID")) | tojson
' "$file" |
while read -r json; do printf '["%s",%s]\n' "$(uuidgen)" "$json"; done |
jq -n --argfile file "$file" '
  reduce inputs as [$id,$json] ($file; setpath($json | fromjson; $id))
'
```

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "10162eb7-29ba-4b60-ad20-e5b1133eca63",
    "Line": [
      {
        "Amount": 100,
        "Description": "Weekly Gardening Service",
        "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
        "Id": "272832df-a8f5-4877-92de-1545150afc33",
        "LineNum": 1,
        "SalesItemLineDetail": {
          "ItemAccountRef": {
            "name": "Landscaping Services",
            "value": "45"
          },
          "ItemRef": {
            "name": "Gardening",
            "value": "6"
          },
          "Qty": 4,
          "TaxCodeRef": {
            "value": "TAX"
          },
          "UnitPrice": 25
        }
      },
      {
        "Amount": 100,
        "DetailType": "SubTotalLineDetail",
        "SubTotalLineDetail": {}
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "190b0e50-e007-46a4-b1ca-c3efb762629c",
    "Line": [
      {
        "Amount": 140,
        "Description": "Weekly Gardening Service",
        "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
        "Id": "f7067227-56d4-4849-873a-3ee5c336999e",
        "LineNum": 1,
        "SalesItemLineDetail": {
          "ItemAccountRef": {
            "name": "Landscaping Services",
            "value": "45"
          },
          "ItemRef": {
            "name": "Gardening",
            "value": "6"
          },
          "Qty": 4,
          "TaxCodeRef": {
            "value": "NON"
          },
          "UnitPrice": 35
        }
      },
      {
        "Amount": 35,
        "Description": "Pest Control Services",
        "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
        "Id": "181d7c6b-0afa-4f44-a568-2c482fc5c285",
        "LineNum": 2,
        "SalesItemLineDetail": {
          "ItemAccountRef": {
            "name": "Pest Control Services",
            "value": "54"
          },
          "ItemRef": {
            "name": "Pest Control",
            "value": "10"
          },
          "Qty": 1,
          "TaxCodeRef": {
            "value": "NON"
          },
          "UnitPrice": 35
        }
      },
      {
        "Amount": 175,
        "DetailType": "SubTotalLineDetail",
        "SubTotalLineDetail": {}
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: In the input Json it's `.Id` but in the one that I have to insert into, it's `id` - I did notice that the `Id`'s in the input are all monotonically increasing, with an intial gap - meaning, generating a random number in a range I could use as a direct id substitution - Not a general solution, but I have this: `'now % (385 - 8) + 8 | floor'`

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to select elements at random from an array, assuming a bash or sufficiently bash-like environment:

```
#!/bin/bash

< /dev/urandom tr -cd '0-9' | fold -w 1 | jq -MRnc '

# Output: a prn in range(0;$n) where $n is `.`
def prn:
  if . == 1 then 0
  else . as $n
  | ([1, (($n-1)|tostring|length)]|max) as $w
  | [limit($w; inputs)] | join("") | tonumber
  | if . < $n then . else ($n | prn) end
  end;

# Input: an array
# Output: an array, being a selection of $k elements from . chosen at random without replacement
def prns($k):
  if $k <= 0 then []
  else . as $in
  | length as $n
  | if $k > $n then "no can do" | error
    else ($n|prn) as $ix
    | [$in[$ix]] + (($in[0:$ix] + $in[$ix+1:])|prns($k-1))
    end
  end;


# Two illustrations
# Three from range(0,10) (with replacement):
[range(0;10) | ( ["a", "b", "c"] | .[length|prn]) ],

# Three from an array, without replacement:
([range(0;10)] | prns(3))

'
```